# Is it possible to authorize users from multiple AD domains?

Tags: linux, authentication, active-directory, kerberos

There is a task to set up AD-authorization of users on Linux servers.
Input data:
2 Active Directory domains. Each in their own forest, but there is a two-way trust relationship between them: domain1.local and domain2.lan
Given:
The task is to connect Linux machines to domain2.lan using sssd, krb5, realm. There are no problems with this, everything is easy and simple. Most importantly, allow users of the domain2.lan domain group (let's say linux-users) to enter, which includes users from both domains, i.e. both domain2.lan and domain1.local.
And if everything is extremely simple and successful with users of domain2.lan, then users of the linux-users group from domain1.local cannot log in in any way.
sshd config:

```
[sssd]
domains = domain2.lan, domain1.local
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam
default_domain_suffix = domain2.lan

[domain/domain2.lan]
ad_domain = domain2.lan
ad_hostname = vs-labs-dc01.domain2.lan
krb5_realm = DOMAIN2.LAN
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
full_name_format = %1$s
use_fully_qualified_names = True
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
access_provider = ad

[domain/domain1.local]
ad_domain = domain1.local
ad_hostname = vs-labs-dc01.domain2.lan
krb5_realm = DOMAIN1.LOCAL
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
full_name_format = %1$s
use_fully_qualified_names = True
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
access_provider = ad
```

Users from domain1.local get:
Permission denied, please try again.
What am I doing wrong? Within the framework of one forest, I think there should be no problems, but there are still 2 different forests, but with bilateral trusts. Everything is ok on win-hosts, users are successfully authorized, but it does not work with Linux.

Answer (score 1):

•   Please check whether cross-domain trust is configured as mutual and the level of compatibility in both domains is accepted, i.e., if one domain is functional at 2003 level and another 2008 then Kerberos tickets validation would be one-way as Windows Server 2008 has more encryption types that 2003 ‘’Function Level’’ doesn't support. You can refer to more details regarding this here: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/security-best-practices/understanding-active-directory-domain-services--ad-ds--functional-levels

•   Also, except the above, please check whether Kerberos realm names are configured as upper-case versions and must be same as Primary DNS names, DNS records are resolvable from all DNS domains in the trust and there is no overlap between IdM and AD DNS domain.

For more details in this scenario for joining and configuring cross forest domain login for Linux systems, please refer to the link below for more details: -

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html-single/windows_integration_guide/index#trust